# Wrong output value in C# programm

Tags: c#, class, oop

Good evening everyone

I recently started learning C#. Since I have already studied C / C ++ many times, and this semester I am studying Java, I thought that it would not be very difficult. But I ran into an unexpected problem.

The task is like this: "There are four persons. Person data is given in such format: name (string), height in meters (double) and weight in kilos (double). Create a class Person to store data about single person. Initial data is entered from keyboard (user input). Write a program that finds average weight of person and calculate which person is the lowest. If multiple persons are found to be the lowest, print them all. At least 3 custom methods must be implemented: for data input, calculation (-s) and for displaying results to the screen.
Print initial data in table format, average weight and all data about the lowest person(-s) to console. Usage of an array of objects is not allowed."

The problem is that in the results table, I have fields Name, Height and Width. And for some reason, the height data is also written to the width field:

```
Write a person`s name-: Artem
Write a person`s height-: 1,81
Write a person`s weight-: 67

Write a person`s name-: Yaroslav
Write a person`s height-: 1,80
Write a person`s weight-: 65,5

Write a person`s name-: Ivan
Write a person`s height-: 1,78
Write a person`s weight-: 70

Write a person`s name-: Ann
Write a person`s height-: 1,78
Write a person`s weight-: 64

Write a person`s name-: x
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       Name     |      Height (m.)     |       Weight (kg.)    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Artem        |          1,81        |    1,81(must be 67)   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Yaroslav     |          1,80        |    1,80(must be 65,5) |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Ivan         |          1,78        |    1,78(must be 70)   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Ann          |          1,78        |    1,78(must be 64)   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I don't even know why this is happening.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Person
{
    internal class Program
    {
        class Person{
            private string name;
            private double width, height;

            public Person(string name, double width, double height) {
                this.name = name;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
            }

            public string GetName() { return name; }
            public double GetHeight() { return height; }
            public double GetWidth() { return width; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            double height, width;
            int count = 0;
            List<Person> person = new List<Person>();

            for (int i = 0; ;i++) {
                name = getName();
                if (name == "X" || name == "x") {
                    break;
                }
                height = getHeight();
                width = getWidth();
                person.Add(new Person(name, height, width));
                count++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("|\tName\t |\tHeight (m.)\t|\tWeight (kg.)\t|");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("|   {0}\t |\t{2,8:f2}\t|\t{2,8:f2}\t|", person[i].GetName(), person[i].GetHeight(), person[i].GetWidth());
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            }

            double avg = SetAverageWidth(person, count);
            Console.WriteLine("\nAvergae width-: {0:f2}", avg);
            Lowest(person, count);
        }

        static string getName() {
            Console.Write("\nWrite a person`s name-: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            return name;
        }
        static double getWidth(){
            Console.Write("Write a person`s width-: ");
            double width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return width;
        }
        static double getHeight(){
            Console.Write("Write a person`s height-: ");
            double height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return height;
        }
        static double SetAverageWidth(List<Person> person, int count)
        {
            double res = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //if (person[i] == null) { break; }
                res += person[i].GetWidth();
            }
            return res / count;
        }
        static void Lowest(List<Person> person, int count) {
            double max, min;
            int i = 0;
        
            max = min = count;
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                if (person[i].GetHeight() > max)
                    max = person[i].GetHeight();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- The Lowest -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- ");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                if (person[j].GetHeight() == max)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("|   {0}\t |\t{2,8:f2}\t|\t{2,8:f2}\t|", person[j].GetName(), person[j].GetHeight(), person[j].GetWidth());
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is... what?  Can you edit your post to state the problem in a sentence or two?

Comment: @Joe, now must be better))

Comment: Your constructor is `public Person(string name, double width, double height)`, but when you called, it you did `person.Add(new Person(name, height, width));`.

Comment: Maybe not related, but I see some mixing up between ***Width*** and ***Weight***. The **text** that you output is `Weight`, but the **variables** and **functions** for that value are named `Width`.

Comment: And, since are _learning_ C#, read up on _Properties_

Comment: `person` isn't really a good name for `List<Person>`. Consider a different name such as `people`, `persons`, etc...

Comment: Well, to be fair guys, the weight of a person also correlates with the width of a person when accounting for height, they're seldomly independent of each other...

Comment: You've reversed the order of the `weight` and `height` arguments.  The function wants them in one order, you supply them in the opposite.  And yes, it's confusing when you name it "width" in on place and "weight" in another

Comment: It's not actually necessary to specify/use the constructor - use properties and see  [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string only uses `{0}` and `{2}`. You're missing `{1}` in line 50:

```
Console.WriteLine("|   {0}\t |\t{2,8:f2}\t|\t{2,8:f2}\t|", person[i].GetName(), person[i].GetHeight(), person[i].GetWidth());
```

and line 106:

```
Console.WriteLine("|   {0}\t |\t{2,8:f2}\t|\t{2,8:f2}\t|", person[j].GetName(), person[j].GetHeight(), person[j].GetWidth());
```

Change the second format string to `{1,8:f2}`.

Other than that:

- check the order of arguments in the constructor of `Person`, you accidentally flipped width and height when you create a new person
- read about properties. C# does not use `Get...()` and `Set...()` methods like Java
- check whether you want *width* or *weight* of the person

Comment: I've made changes like that `{0}\t |\t{2,8:f1}\t|\t{2,8:f2}\t` but they still don't work.

Comment: @Sollpix `{0}\t |\t{1,8:f2}\t|\t{2,8:f2}\t` - you need to change directly after the `{`.

Answer (score -1):

```
        public Person(string name, double width, double height) {
```

and

```
   person.Add(new Person(name, height, width));
```

you have the arguments in the wrong order